# Como utilizar Trigger para insertar en más de una tabla?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, trigger, mysql-workbench

Estoy utilizando el gestor de base de datos MYSql, tengo creadas las tablas t_u_user, t_u_phoneCode, t_u_cidBirthDate y t_u_nameEmail y la tabla sobre la cual estoy realizando el trigger es t_u_user.

El objetivo es que después de haberse realizado una insert en la tabla t_u_user este debería ejecutar el disparador e insertar en las otras tres tabla los datos correspondiente.

Les agradezco la ayuda; Es posible esto? existe alguna alternativa?

```
DELIMITER 
$$
CREATE TRIGGER updat_auxiliar_tables AFTER INSERT ON 
       t_u_user FOR EACH ROW 
INSERT INTO t_u_phoneCode (
       codcountrypm, 
       phoneMovil, 
       code, 
       registerDate
) 
VALUES (
       new.codcountrypm,
       new.phoneMovil,
       new.codPhoneMovil,sysdate
)$$
INSERT INTO t_u_cidBirthDate (
       cidPassport, 
       birthDate, 
       registerDate
) 
VALUES (
       new.cidOrPassport,
       new.birthDate,
       sysdate
)$$
INSERT INTO t_u_nameEmail (
       firstName, 
       lastName, 
       email, 
       registerDate
) 
VALUES (
       new.firstName, 
       new.lastName,
       new.email,
       sysdate
)$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Error que muestra pruebas realizadas:

[image: Error que muestra al ejecutar el siguiente codigo]

Valides de la creación del primer insert into:

[image: Solo reconoce el primer insert]

Otras pruebas, donde cambio de posición los insert para validar el query creado.
[image: Prueba1 Error2]

Resultado del trigger.
[image: Se reconoce el primer inserto into realizado, mientras que los demás no]

Comment: y esto no anda? tira algun error? lo probaste? tuviste algun problema?

Comment: Si el error lo muestra en el segundo insert, adjuntare imágenes donde veras que al momento de crear el trigger como que no reconoce el segundo insert, realizo la prueba cambiando los insert, y definitivamente el segundo registro no lo reconoce.

Comment: y esas columnas estan en la tabla donde esta el trigger?

Comment: Si exacto las columnas que se muestran después del `new.` esta en la tabla del trigger.

Comment: creo que te falta un begin (despues del for) y un end...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dejo un ejemplo simplificado a tu pregunta original, te servirá como guía, te explico en que consiste: hay 3 tablas y se llaman; `foo`, `new` y `old`. Solo se crea un **TRIGGER** en la tabla `foo` llamado `example` que detecta cuando se hace un **INSERT** y este replica dicho **INSERT** a las tablas `new` y `old`.

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  value VARCHAR(10)
);

CREATE TABLE new (
  id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  value VARCHAR(10)
);

CREATE TABLE old (
  id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  value VARCHAR(10)
);
```

El trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER example AFTER INSERT ON foo FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO new (value)
  VALUES (new.value);

  INSERT INTO old (value)
  VALUES (new.value);
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Luego hacemos un **INSERT** de prueba:

```
INSERT INTO foo (value) VALUES ('a');
```

Por último haces un **SELECT** a cada tabla en cuestión para comprobar:

```
SELECT * FROM foo;
SELECT * FROM new;
SELECT * FROM old;
```

Espero que sea útil.

Comment: Esto es lo que estás buscando @HarryAlvarado ?

Comment: Hola @Nicola Strappazzon , me fue muy útil tu ejemplo excelente, Gracias a ello pudo resolver, Gracias!!; por lo que veo creo que me faltaron algunos punto y coma. pero bueno de igual manera hasta eso había revisado antes de preguntas...

Comment: @HarryAlvarado No te olvides de indicar que la respuesta es la correcta.